# Conway exercise on analytic functions

Tags: complex-analysis

> Suppose $f_n$ is a sequence in $H(G)$, the space of analytic functions on a region $G \subset \mathbf{C}$, converging to a non-constant function $f$ in $H(G)$. Let $a \in G$ and $f(a)=\alpha$. Show that there is a sequence $\{a_n\}$ in $G$ such that $a_n \to a$ and $f_n(a_n)=\alpha$ for large $n$.

Attempt: I know I am supposed to use Hurwitz theorem, so to introduce zeros, we can assume $\alpha=0$, otherwise consider $g_n=f_n-\alpha$.

Since $f(a)=0$ and $f$ is non-constant, it has isolated zeros and we can find $r>0$ such that $f$ is non-zero on $\overline{B(a,r)}\setminus\{a\}$. By Hurwitz, there exists $N$ such that $f_n$ has at least one zero in $B(a,r)$.

Now my idea was to keep shrinking the radius of this ball and find corresponding zeros of $f_n$ and show that they satisfy the result. But I am unable to show this rigorously.

Comment: You failed to say that the convergence is uniform on compact subsets.

Comment: @TedShifrin: That is probably implied by “convergence in $H(G)$.”